# Can't access variable value in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of values:

```
var info_tab = [
                ["Aaaa", 53.12040528310657, 23.258056640625,1,ikona3],
                ["Bbbb", 53.09402405506325, 18.0010986328125,2,ikona2],
            ];
```

Here I use it in a function to pass values as parameters The problem is with this section: `label: info_tab[i][1]`:

```
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        icon: ikona2,
        label: info_tab[i][1]
      });
    });
```

I am getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.

However, I show this via  `window.alert(info_tab[i][1])` and it shows a good value. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: What is the variable `i`?

Comment: per [Array.Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), i is the index of the array item

Comment: its index, see - it's .map loop function.

Comment: @James I know that `i` is, I wonder what the value actually is. My guess is the index is greater than the length of the array with the detail.

Comment: The error message implies that info_tab[i] is undefined - @epascarello you're probably right, the info_tab array is shorter than the locations array.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will add a label to a marker with either 53.12040528310657 or 53.09402405506325. Label is required to be a string.

To convert number to a string use `info_tab[i][1].toString()`

> A marker label is a letter or number that appears inside a marker. The marker image in this section displays a marker label with the letter 'B' on it. You can specify a marker label as either a string or a MarkerLabel object that includes a string and other label properties.

```js
var info_tab = [
  ["Aaaa", 53.12040528310657, 23.258056640625,1,'icon1'],
  ["Bbbb", 53.09402405506325, 18.0010986328125,2,'icon12'],
];
            
var locations = [
  {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044},
  {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044},
]

var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
    var label = info_tab[i][1]; 
    
    console.log(label.toString()); // '53.12040528310657'

});
```